# Random Action AI controller for Java game

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

Im trying to implement a basic game AI for my enemy ships that performs random actions (i.e turns and shoots, then moves forward, then maybe turns around and shoots etc). I have made a basic AI that simply rotates and shoots.

Here is the RotateAndShoot AI:

```
public class RotateAndShoot implements Controller {
Action action = new Action();

@Override
public Action action() {
    action.shoot = true;
    action.thrust = 1; //1=on 0=off
    action.turn = -1; //-1 = left 0 = no turn 1 = right
    return action;
}
}
```

Here is the Controller class if this helps explain:

```
public interface Controller {
public Action action();
}
```

These use a class called Action which just provides some variables that are assigned to actions (such as public int thrust, which if turned to an on state, moves the ship forward). How can i go about implementing a form of AI which just does a bunch of random actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Math.random() or Random.

Here is solution for Random:

```
@Override
public Action action() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    action.shoot = rand.nextBoolean();
    action.thrust = rand.nextInt(2);
    action.turn = rand.nextInt(3) - 1;
    return action;
}
```